# I want to create application for linux system and i want to know how to modify open source application like vestacp webmin

Tags: application-development

I am a very beginner in linux development..plz explain what i want to learn to build linux application or develop or modify open source application

Comment: I don't know that application, but if it's an open source program I have installed, `apt source` to grab the source code (assuming I'd enabled source (src) for download), and use that as a starting point. To upload, by far the easiest is via PPA (3rd party repository) as I don't need anyone to review/check my code (my responsibility) allowing easy testing by me or other team members, before I'd think about submitting code/fixes upstream etc.  (there is some setup for of keys etc for PPA, but covered in questions on this site already, let alone official docs I'd go for myself)

Answer (score 0):

1. clone source code
2. edit with any compatible ide of choice
3. compile with any compatible compiler of choice